# My browser has no errors for localStorage

Tags: javascript

Well, I am on a school computer, so I can't check the dev console. But I would like some help figuring out why this does not save to the localStorage.

```
var editor = document.getElementById('editor');
var output = document.getElementById('output');
var textInput = document.getElementById('textSaveInput');
var textOutput = document.getElementById('textSaveStat');
editor.addEventListener('input', function() {
  output.innerText = editor.value;
});

function saveTexteditor() {
  localStorage.setItem(textInput.value, editor.value);
  textOutput.innerHTML = "Saved as file " + textInput.value;
}

function loadTexteditor() {
  editor.value = localStorage.getItem(textInput.value);
  textOutput.innerHTML = "Loaded file " + textInput.value;
}
```

I tried running it through a compiler and it worked fine, but it does not work in the browser

Comment: You never call the `save` or `load` functions.

Comment: If you can't check the console, how do you know there are no errors?

Comment: @Gaberocksall It is called inside the html, sorry I did not link it.